# после добавления в Django проект главную страницу сайта вылезает большая ошибка

Tags: python, django

код urls.py файла главной страницы:

```
from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index )
    ]
```

код главной urls.py файла:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main/urls.py'))
]
```

в папке main (не основном) еще файл views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h4>Hello<h4/>")
```

вылезает ошибка в терминале:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main/urls'
Там еще очень много текста, поэтому не запихну сюда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отделяйте название модуля точкой, расширение файла не указывайте.

***Пример:***

```py
path('', include('main.urls'))  # Вместо 'main/urls.py'
```